# Can't allocate enough memory in JNI

Tags: android, c++, memory, memory-management, java-native-interface

I have an android native shared library (.so) that is used in an android application. This library was originally written for windows/desktop, and then ported to mobile platforms. It contains an "algorithmic" code, which works on large data set. Within the library I don't use a standard heap (`malloc` and friends), instead memory pages are allocated via `mmap` with flags `MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS` and then partitioned appropriately.

Now, the problem is that at some point `mmap` fails with error code = 12, which is **out-of-memory**. This happens when the total allocated memory size reaches about **650MB**. I know this value if pretty large, and way above what a typical android application needs. But in my specific case this is legitimate IMHO, since this is indeed what this library/application does, and this is realized and approved by the user.

Specifically I try to run this on Samsung tablet SM-T800, which has 3GB RAM, a 32-bit armeabi-v7a architecture, and more than 7GB of free storage space (flash memory). So that *technically* there should be no problem.

Also this is not a problem of virtual memory fragmentation: the `mmap` fails when I ask to allocate additional memory chunk of as much as **16MB**. So, most probably some artificial limitation is imposed by the system on how many memory pages can be allocated for the process.

So, my question is, if and how this limitation can be removed. From what I found in online documentation, there is no mention of this limitation, but I'm pretty sure it exists. I've also read in some forums that starting from Android 5.0 some applications fail to allocate as much memory as they could in older systems.

In case this limitation can't be removed, would it help to work with file mapping? Currently I store the data in source files in a compressed way, then I read it and build a complex data structure in memory. Instead I could store the whole data structure in a file (means, the file would be larger), and just map it into memory via `mmap`. The total size of the virtual address space would be the same, but if the limitation is not on its size, but on how many pages are allocated and not backed by a file - this could work.

As a last resort I can abandon the idea of having all the data in (virtual) memory, and manually read & lock only the data portions that I currently need, and discard those that are not used recently. But by such a way I actually duplicate the work of memory manager, since the paging mechanism does exactly this.

Thanks in advance.